# Possible to have a php function with two names?

Tags: php, function

Odd ball question, but I'm stuck with an old function library that has too still be used.  My question, is it possible to have a function with two names?  ie:

```
function fReturnFormatedDateOrNull($string, $switch=1), fDoN ($string, $switch=1) {
  gutshere
}
```

I hate the name space / length of the first name, but I need to keep the function.  I would like to use a shorthand name (fDoN) going forward.  Or am I stuck creating the new function and calling the old one?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what about `function fDoN ($string, $switch) return fReturnFormatedDateOrNull($string, $switch)`

Comment: Call one from the other? Deprecate the old one?

Comment: fDoN is a horrible name for a function. I beg you to please spare future developers from trying to figure out what in the heck that means.

Comment: Yeah, I go from using crazy long function names to wanting to shorten everything up way to much.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: c'mon... hungarian notation? `fWhatever()` is so utterly pointless... there goes one character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply Stated, No

However you can do this to make it easier...

```
function fReturnFormatedDateOrNull($string, $switch=1) {
    gutshere
}

function fDoN($string, $switch=1) {
    fReturnFormatedDateOrNull($string,$switch);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)